# Migrate from JS, errors in tsc build

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, migration

I'm trying out TypeScript for the first time and am migrating an existing JavaScript codebase.

I've followed the directions on the TS [migration guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) but ran into build problems right away.

The main blocker I'm hitting is that `tsc` is complaining about trying to compile a `.ts` file that lives in my `node_modules` directory.

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "__tests__"]
}
```

As you can see, I've *tried* to tell `tsc` to ignore the `node_modules` directory, but it looks like it's still going in there.

This is the error - though I'm not sure how helpful it is:

```
node_modules/http-link-dataloader/dist/src/types.d.ts:14:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RequestInit'.

14     referrerPolicy?: RequestInit['referrerPolicy'];
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need a `"skipLibCheck": true` in compiler options.

Via: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14293

Edit: Digging into this further you shouldn't really need to skipLibCheck. The issue is that TS is looking into the definitions for http-link-dataloader and it cannot find RequestInit.

Looking into the definition file for http-link-dataloader it does not actually define the type for RequestInit:

https://github.com/prisma/http-link-dataloader/blob/master/src/types.ts

Further digging has lead me to find that RequestInit is actually part of fetch. [Relevant GitHub Issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/207)

In order to use typings for client side js like fetch you'll want to use the **dom** library in typescript.

```
"lib": [
    "dom",
    ...
]
```

Comment: That did the trick. The docs say that `skipLibCheck` is "Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts)." - what does that actually mean for my project? Was I missing something or am I at risk of something important being missing?

Comment: skipLibCheck will stop typescript from going into the library and verifying it's use of types in the library match what are said to be exported. Digging into this deeper though it seems that RequestInit, is actually a newer type that is defined as part of fetch. I'll amend my answer with some comments.